# Prefill Mustache.JS Template with Values from Mongo DB (Mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mustache

I am currently having a list with some entries in my database. Now i want the users to be able to edit one of those entries.

When the "Edit" Button is clicked, it should load the original form and prefill all the fields with the values already stored in the database.

I used a mustache template for my form, looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Issue Form</h1>
<p>{{ errors }}</p>

<form method="post">

<label>Title: <br><input type="text" name="title">{{ value }}</label><br>

<label>Description: <br><textarea type="text" name="description">{{ value }} 
</textarea></label><br>

<label>Priority: <br>

<select name="priority">
<option>high</option>
<option>medium</option>
<option>low</option>
</select>

</label><br>

<input type="submit" value="Save Entry">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my mongoose schema:

```
var issueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  priority: String
});
```

I of course did a lot of researche on how to fill my fields. I read about the mongoose "populate()" function, but when i tried to use it, there was always some errors telling me that the function itself is undefined.
Another option was using a JSON file to store the data values, but i cannot do this in this example since the values should always be stored in my MongoDB data folder.

Another version i found was creating an object via the toObject() function. But anytime i tried that out:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {

  var objectForEditing = issueModel.findOne(req.params.id).toObject;
  console.log(objectForEditing);
  res.render('issueFormEdit');

});
```

The console.log part shows me the object as undefined.

Using JQuery like i did in any other javascript file before didn't work either, even when including the modules.

*I simply need a method to connect my javascript code with my hjs file.* But i simply am not able to do so, my knowledge is not enough for this. I really tried out a lot and have invested hours so far. But i simply can't get to the bottom on how to connect these two files.

This is my first time ever working with this combination of Mustache.JS and MongoDB/Mongoose/Express. Please be gentle :(

If any more code is needed, please just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the following list of issues:

1) `Model.prototype.findOne()` method is asynchronous, so you either need to use `async/await` or use promises before calling `toObject()` on it.

2) You are querying mongoose in the wrong way. You need to use `findOneById(id)` or `findOne({ _id: id })`.

3) `toObject` is a function, so it has to be called.

4) `objectForEditing` needs to be passed to `res.render` function as the second argument which represents [locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render), which basically is:

> an object whose properties define local variables for the view

Try this code (async/await):

```
router.get('/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
  let objectForEditing = await issueModel.findOneById(req.params.id);
  objectForEditing = objectForEditing.toObject();
  res.render('issueFormEdit', objectForEditing);
});
```

Using Promises:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
      issueModel.findOneById(req.params.id)
        .then(issue => {
          const objectForEditing = issue.toObject();
          res.render('issueFormEdit', objectForEditing);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The Promise Version was exactly the thing i needed. Thank you a lot for ponting out my errors as well. This helped me a lot !!